# Python and character normalization

Tags: python, django, utf-8, diacritics, transliteration

Hello
I retrieve text based utf8 data from a foreign source which contains special chars such as `u"ıöüç"` while I want to normalize them to English such as `"ıöüç"` -> `"iouc"` . What would be the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Search and replace maybe, you'll have to have a full array of special to normal characters though.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I recommend using [Unidecode module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/):

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode(u'ıöüç')
'iouc'
```

Note how you feed it a unicode string and it outputs a byte string. The output is guaranteed to be ASCII.

Answer (score 7):

It all depends on how far you want to go in transliterating the result. If you want to convert everything all the way to ASCII (`αβγ` to `abg`) then `unidecode` is the way to go.

If you just want to remove accents from accented letters, then you could try decomposing your string using normalization form NFKD (this converts the accented letter `á` to a plain letter `a` followed by `U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT`) and then discarding the accents (which belong to the [Unicode character class](http://www.unicode.org/Public/5.1.0/ucd/UCD.html#Canonical_Combining_Class_Values) `Mn` — "Mark, nonspacing").

```
import unicodedata

def remove_nonspacing_marks(s):
    "Decompose the unicode string s and remove non-spacing marks."
    return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s)
                   if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I found:

`unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s).encode("ascii", "ignore")`

Answer (score 0):

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.normalize()
```

http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html

Comment: I am abit confused: I have tried 
print unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u"ıöüç") and the output is again: ıöüç

Comment: Try the other valid values ‘NFC’, ‘NFKC’, ‘NFD’, and ‘NFKD’.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is a different operation than what the asker is looking for. But yes, this is unicode normalization. What he is asking is not usually referred as such.

Comment: Right. It's referred to as `transliteration` I think.