# removing accent and special characters

Tags: python, diacritics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to remove accents in a python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)
>   [Python and character normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162603/python-and-character-normalization)

I would like to remove accents, turn all characters to lowercase, and delete any numbers and special characters.

*Example :*

Frédér8ic@ --> frederic

*Proposal:*

```
def remove_accents(data):
    return ''.join(x for x in unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', data) if \
    unicodedata.category(x)[0] == 'L').lower()
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include some examples of desired input and output?

Comment: @Christian Jonassen Frédér8ic@ --> frederic @@àbcd --> abcd %*tréçd --> trecd

Comment: This is possibly not a duplicate considering OP wanted something more than unicode normalization.

Comment: @Abhijit +1. I search more efficient than my code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A possible solution would be

```
def remove_accents(data):
    return ''.join(x for x in unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', data) if x in string.printable).lower()
```

Using NFKD AFAIK is the standard way to normalize unicode to convert it to compatible characters. The rest as to remove the special characters numbers and unicode characters that originated from normalization, you can simply compare with `string.ascii_letters` and remove any character's not in that set.

Comment: But what is the string variable in that command? 
Where you refer `if x in string.ascii_letters`

Comment: @Falcoa is rigth. There's another solution

    def remove_accents(self, data):
        return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', data).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')

Answer (score 1):

Can you convert the string into HTML entities? If so, you can then use a simple regular expression.

The following replacement would work in PHP/PCRE (see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2103815/89771) for an example):

```
'~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i' => '$1'
```

Then simply convert back from HTML entities and remove any non `a-Z` char ([demo @ CodePad](http://codepad.org/WsSncbO3)).

Sorry I don't know Python enough to provide a Pythonic answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that the regex are more efficient than UnicodeData

Comment: @user1125315: I'm not sure either, but it correctly passes your input/output tests. Feel free to try other approaches though, the `unidecode` lib seems awesome.