# accent characters not showing properly in browser

Tags: php, sql-server

In districts table 
I have a row as

```
district_id   district_name   country_id
15            Šahty           16
```

While selecting from php and displaying in browser,it shows like this :�ahty

I am using mssql 2005 with collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

The problem is something like this 
[removing accent and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694815/removing-accent-and-special-characters)
but i need the solution in php.

UPDATE(?):
There is no support for UTF-8 in sqlserver.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/mssql-2005-2008-utf-8-collation-charset

Comment: Is your web server supplying the same charset to the HTML, or do you have a `<meta>` charset specified in the output HTML?

Comment: You don't need to remove the accents, just instruct the browser how they should be interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to consider correct HTML content type header

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Data may be selected correctly, but browser may be can not displayed them as you expected.
You can play with this in firefox by Menu View -> Character encoding -> until you find correct one

Comment: He specifically said his charset being `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, which is, last time I checked, not utf8.

Comment: I said, correct meta header, snipped I provided is just example, not solution, but ok...

Comment: It's not clear from your answer, consider adding "For example:" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make special characters work, a general rule is that all the components must be on the same encoding. This means that database, database connection (very often forgotten 'SET NAMES {charset}' call after connecting to database) and web page Content-type have to be all in the same character set.

If you ask data from latin1 database and have database connection also has latin1, make sure the page you display values at is also latin1.

It's recommended though to use UTF-8 instead of latin1 everywhere, so if possible I recommending changing charsets and data in your database all to UTF-8, as it's more compatible all-around and easier to handle.

Comment: So, there is no way to change charsets in sqlserver 2005 database to UTF-8.                               http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/mssql-2005-2008-utf-8-collation-charset

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the UTF8 charset and let the browser select the charset it will set to ISO-8859-1 that will work with accents in sql server

Comment: being more specific will help this answer