# Compare 2 strings without considering accents in Python

Tags: python, string

I would like to compare 2 strings and have `True` if the strings are identical, without considering the accents.

Example : I would like the following code to print 'Bonjour'

```
if 'séquoia' in 'Mon sequoia est vert':
    print 'Bonjour'
```

Comment: Convert to fully decomposed normal form, remove accents, compare.

Comment: Linked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `unidecode` function from [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) package:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

if unidecode(u'séquoia') in 'Mon sequoia est vert':
    print 'Bonjour'
```

Answer (score 6):

You should take a look at [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1). With the module and this method, you can get a string without accent and then make your comparaison:

```
def remove_accents(data):
    return ''.join(x for x in unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', data) if x in string.ascii_letters).lower()


if remove_accents('séquoia') in 'Mon sequoia est vert':
    # Do something
    pass
```

[Reference from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694815/removing-accent-and-special-characters)

Comment: This would not work if the word was "séQuoIa" since the `remove_accents` method makes all of the characters lowercase.

Answer (score 6):

(*sorry, late to the party!!*)

How about instead, doing this:

```
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u'î ï í ī į ì').encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
'i i i i i i'
```

No need to loop over anything. @Maxime Lorant answer is very inefficient.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> code = """
import string, unicodedata
def remove_accents(data):
    return ''.join(x for x in unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', data) if x in string.ascii_letters).lower()
"""
>>> timeit.timeit("remove_accents(u'séquoia')", setup=code)
3.6028339862823486
>>> timeit.timeit("unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u'séquoia').encode('ASCII', 'ignore')", setup='import unicodedata')
0.7447490692138672
```

*Hint: less is better*

Also, I'm sure the package `unidecode` @Seur suggested has other advantages, but it is still very slow compared to the native option that requires no 3rd party libraries.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u'séquoia').encode('ASCII', 'ignore')", setup="import unicodedata")
0.7662729263305664
>>> timeit.timeit("unidecode.unidecode(u'séquoia')", setup="import unidecode")
7.489392042160034
```

*Hint: less is better*

Putting it all together:

```
clean_text = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u'séquoia').encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
if clean_text in 'Mon sequoia est vert':
    ...
```